# System.Threading.Timer expiring hundreds of milliseconds late

Tags: c#

I'm using a System.Threading.Timer which is configured to expire in 100ms. Typically it will call the callback method within 10ms of the expected time, however, the callback is frequently called up to 500ms late. By frequent, I mean around 25% of the time.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Timers are not supposed to messure time exactly. Indeed they are expiring later. Have a look at the StopWatch-class.

Comment: You might want to read through "[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)", the thing you are looking for is "Metronome-quality beat" (note the astrix on the line talking about that feature, that limitation is what Hans and Valery are talking about in their answers).

Answer (score 5):

Well, 500 msec is in fact a magic number in a .NET program.  That's how often the threadpool manager considers adding another thread to the pool because the existing ones appear to be stuck and not making progress.  The Timer callback is made on a tp thread.

So, sight unseen, a conclusion you can draw is that the callback cannot run soon enough because you have far too many threadpool threads active in your program.  So the timer callback only gets a chance to run when the tp manager forcibly adds another thread to the pool.

If accurate, this is pretty unhealthy.  Could be that you have a lot of tp threads that are burning 100% core.  Easy to see from Task Manager, you'll see the CPU usage completely pegged at 100%.  But far more common is that they are not being used effectively, instead of executing code they are blocking.  Most typically on an I/O request, a socket read or dbase query for example.  Such code should *not* run on a tp thread, it should run on a regular Thread or a Task that was configured with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.  Or made more efficient by making it asynchronous, the C# v5 asych/await keywords can make that a lot easier.

A sledge-hammer solution is to call ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() and bump up the minimum.  Only ever consider this if you cannot afford the time to do it right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I should have said that I'd already tried bumping up the minimum number of threads when we originally encountered the problem. Upping it from 4 to 32 seemed to have no effect. Having said that, it's always possible that we are exceeding 32, and this is clearly something worth investigating.

Comment: Yeah, you certainly should have mentioned that.  Well, sledge-hammer doesn't work, fix the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

1) your OS is not RTOS (RealTime OS)

2) System.Threading.Timer executes its callback on thread from ThreadPool and it can guarantee only the fact that callback will be called after time interval elapsed.